# Correct placement of "not" next to "to" disambiguating a sentence

Tags: grammar, word-order, negation

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59478872/1525840) on another site and got corrected by someone. Them being NSE and me not, I appreciated the improvement except in one regard - placement of the negation. So I asked about it and as it turns out, they wasn't certain neither and we decided to ask here.

> I'd also *prefer **to not** use a method* valid in an older version of PS, although working, if there's a more convenient approach in a later one.

I've been taught that it's incorrect to place *not* after the infinite marker *to*, so the original wording was hence like this.

> I'm also *concerned **not to** use a method* valid in an older version of PS, although working, if there's a more convenient approach in a later one.

Partially, we're not entirely certain which is correct. Partially, they indicated that the construction might be ambiguous and difficult to interpret, even if it'd be grammatically correct.

1. Which formulation is correct?
2. Is the sentence ambiguous?

I believe [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48509/30362) covers the matter of grammatical correctness and colloquial frequency. Although, it doesn't address the issue of ambiguity.

The indented meaning is intentionally left at the very end to avoid unconsciously influencing the reader. The point was that I prefer to use modern approach. It's possible that the same effect may be reached using different command patterns (one older - widely spread, and one newer - not well known yet but improved in terms of syntax, features etc.). Me being less experienced in the area, can't reliably decide whether it's the case. So, while inclined to using newer methodology, I raise no demand on the modernity, still wishing to mention the preference.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112893/to-not-vs-not-to?rq=1. _Although working_ is the problematic bit to me; it would be clearer to say _even though it may work_ or _even though it works_.

Comment: @KateBunting Good link. It gave me lead on even better one. It addresses the correctness of the matter but not ambiguity, though. I altered the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity caused by the placement of _not_.

Comment: Note the way user Kate Bunting addressed that — the ambiguity isn't caused by *to not* or *not to* in this case, but rather by the choice of word (*concerned*). The original is ambiguous / difficult to parse as it stands. As far as that particular issue (the order of *not* and *to*) is concerned, it all comes down to how it sounds to a native speaker of English, and the advice/usage outlined in the answer on ELU you've linked to is sound. I agree that *although working* is sort of like a parentless child in that sentence, and it's not clear what it's referring to.

Comment: @userr2684291 Ah, now I got it. I'm convinced that your interpretation of Kate's comment is accurate. Regrettably, it wasn't apparent to me, so I appreciate your explicit elaboration. And I thank you both, of course. It's not a criticism of Kate's answer - rather a remark on my cognitive insufficiency.   :)

Comment: Editor from the Stack Overflow question here: I was trying to preserve the original conversational tone. After giving it some more thought, perhaps something like this would be clearer: _"Backward compatibility is unimportant if a modern PowerShell feature would allow for a more convenient approach."_ However, I feel like this is mostly just avoiding the question here. I would love to see a fleshed out answer that addresses the phrases in this question rather than a workaround.

Comment: @BoogaRoo I agree with you regarding the *flesh-out*, however, I claim that *avoiding* is a poor choice of word, as it bears slightly negative connotation. While undeniably being an avoidance, your formulation's precisely what I should've used. So even if it doesn't constitute a full and definitive answer, it behooves the readers by presenting an excellent alternative for future usages. And the site's primarily about *English language **learning*** (structured, on-topic answers being merely a means to it).

Comment: @BoogaRoo I'd love you to post an answer including both point presented in [this linked answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48509/30362) as well as the trully excellent suggestion  in your comment. You seem to know your way around the lingo and are utterly proper and thorough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the original word that felt out of place was "concerned." I think it could still be used with a slight adjustment to place emphasis on "concerned" instead of "use." The phrasing of "although working" was also noted to be a bit ambiguous. It can be left off since it's not really critical to the preference expressed in the sentence.

If I were to rephrase the original again, I would go with this:

> I'm also not concerned about using a method valid in older versions of
>   PowerShell if there's a more convenient approach in a later one.

All that being said, the concept you're describing has a term for it: [backward compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility). While gratuitous use of jargon can sometimes make things difficult to read, this is a case where I feel it improves readability.

This is what I would suggest using instead:

> Backward compatibility is unimportant if a modern PowerShell feature
>   would allow for a more convenient approach.

---

As for the question of "to not use" versus "not to use" the weight is heavily in favor of "not to use" at about 94% of occurrences according to the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).

The [linked answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/48509/30362) from user [Colin Fine](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/547/colin-fine) made a couple of excellent points included here for reference:

> The normal form of a negative infinitive is "not to X", in all
>   contexts.
>
> The form "to not X" is grammatical (notwithstanding the generations of
>   people who have moaned about "splitting the infinitive"), but unusual,
>   and would only be used in order to convey a special meaning.

Comment: P.S. I'm sure there is a similar term in other languages for "backward compatibility" but it's completely understandable to not know the exact phrase. Like a great many things in tech you won't know what term to look for, but you'll know exactly what you needed the instant you see it. Link included for future readers, just in case they're not familiar with it.